# Splunk Alert - setting different threshold during the day

Tags: alert, splunk

I need to set up splunk alert with the following scenario:
Between 2:01 AM and 4:59 AM - If the count of 5xx error is less than 5 then send Alert
Between 5:00 AM - 2:00 AM - If the count of 5xx error is less than 25 then send Alert
Is there a way in Splunk to do this? Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do that.  The first is to define two alerts with different thresholds and cron schedules.

The second way is to have a single alert that tests the current time before deciding on a threshold.

```
| eval threshold = if((now() > relative_time(now(), "@d+2h")) AND (now() < relative_time(now(), "@d+5h")), 5, 25)
| where count > threshold
```

The `relative_time` function skews the first argument by the interval given in the second argument.  In this case, the current time is set to midnight (0:00, "@d") plus 2 or 5 hours ("+2h" or "+5h").